# Task Scheduler won't run simple tasks in Windows Server 2016

Tags: task, scheduler, windows-server-2016

I can't get Task Scheduler to run my tasks so I setup a simple tasks to see if it there was something wrong with the system. The tasks I created was open a command prompt at a specific time. Tasks Scheduler says it's running, but the cmd prompt doesn't open. Then I tried running it manually and still it doesn't work. I used my administrator account and the system account, but neither worked. Any ideas?

Comment: https://danblee.com/log-on-as-batch-job-rights-for-task-scheduler/log-on-as-batch-job-rights/

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the tasks to run using Powershell, but this still doesn't explain what is causing Tasks Scheduler to not run simple tasks.

Comment: Task Scheduler works. If it didn't, you'd notice a lot of things failing on Windows. You haven't provided any information about the tasks you created though so it's impossible to guess what's wrong. It's quite likely the task works but you don't realize it - any application that interacts with the desktop will appear in the desktop of the user it's configured to run under. Or the command line may simply be wrong - there's no reason to start a command line prompt just to run a batch file. If you used `cmd`, you probably fired off a command prompt that exited immediatelly

Comment: The reason for this simple task is to test if something is blocking my tasks from actually executing. I also created a tasks to open Notepad. In both cases, Windows says the tasks completed successfully, but neither Notepad or command prompt actually opens. I created the notepad tasks on my local computer and it works with no problem. This tells me that something is blocking me on the server side. I should have mentioned above that I'm trying this on a server in Azure.

Comment: The problem is the task itself then. That's definitely **not** a simple task - by default the Task Scheduler does *not* interact with the use's desktop. Otherwise you'd be interrupted all the time by executing tasks. I suspect you'll find at least one orphaned instance of `NotePad.exe` running in Task Manager

Comment: If you want to test how Task Scheduler works, write a batch file (either CMD or PoweShell) that does something that *doesn't* require desktop interaction, like appending a line to a file

Comment: Appending text to an existing file worked!. What I don't understand is why I can run the exact Tasks, Open Notepad on my local computer(windows10), but not on a server(windows 2019). This is very confusing.

Comment: hi, how did you get it to run?